# C# equivalent to MySQL Data and Time data types

Tags: c#, mysql, types

Now Timestamp and DateTime are equivalent to System.DateTime but what do I convert Date and Time to?  Do I just convert them to DateTime and know on the date or time is set or is their a specific datatype for those?  I am using NHibernate as my ORM if it has a specific conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You convert them to `DateTime`.  `DateTime` has `Date` and `TimeOfDay` if you need to seperate them out.

Comment: `Date` would be rather useless, since all it does is return a `DateTime` instance with the time information zeroed out, which is exactly how it would come out of the database for a `date` field.